# Ruby on rails + Tiny TDS not connecting to sql epxress

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, tiny-tds

I'm trying to get a rails app to connect to a SQL Express instance. I'm working in a windows environment.

I don't want to setup a DSN so I went with Tindy TDS. Unfortunately, I can't get it to work.

When I execute

```
rake db:migrate
```

I see

```
rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
closed connection
C:/site/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

and when I run the trace, I see

```
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
closed connection
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-3.2.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver_adap
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-3.2.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver_adap
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-3.2.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver_adap
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-3.2.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver_adap
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-3.2.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver_adap
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-3.2.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver_adap
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-3.2.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver_adap
'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:315:
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:325:
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:247:
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:239:
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:102:
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:101:
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:410:
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specificatio
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specificatio
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:308:in `clear_cache!'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:97:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:418:in `_run__107948286__prepare__477
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_prepare_callbacks'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:74:in `prepare!'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:48:in `prepare!'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:47:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
C:/rorblog/rorblog/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application.rb:297:in `block (2 levels) in initialize_tasks'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:228:in `call'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:228:in `block in execute'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:223:in `each'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:223:in `execute'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:166:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:159:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:187:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:185:in `each'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:185:in `invoke_prerequisites'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:159:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:152:in `invoke'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:143:in `invoke_task'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `each'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block in top_level'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `run_with_threads'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in `top_level'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:73:in `block in run'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby193/bin/rake:23:in `load'
C:/Ruby193/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
```

My database.yml is

```
development:
  adapter: sqlserver
  database: MyDatabase
  dataserver: localhost\SQLEXPRESS
  mode: dblib
  username: sa
  password: "1234"
```

In the trace file I see "method missing" but no idea if thats the problem or if it's something else.

Answer (score -2):

Updated my environment.rb file to add error catching

```
begin
  MySite::Application.initialize!
rescue Exception => ex
  puts '--------------------'
  puts ex.message
  puts '--------------------'
end
```

and I can see that TinyTDS is giving an error

```
--------------------
Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist
--------------------
```

So now I have to figure that out.